# Canon 7d or 70d can't decide

Tags: canon-7d

I can't decide to purchase the canon 7d now or wait for the 70d in September. Does anyone have thoughts on this? I have been waiting for a good while saving for a great camera and had almost decided until I heard about the 70d. So with it being new and the 7d a few years old...
what do you think?
Janet

Comment: Hi Janet, Welcome to Photo.SE. This question doesn't really fit into the scope of what we do here **as it is currently**. With more information about your specific needs/wants, budget and use, we may be able to provide assistance, although we are looking for questions that have look at how to decide (i.e. what features are useful for X, or why feature A is more desirable than feature B etc.) rather than at asking us for suggestions or a decision because questions that ask the latter type of question will still be relevant in many years to come and the same issues and problems will still exist.

Comment: @damnedtruths - I think in this particular case, the comparison is obvious enough to draw a conclusion without needing further detail.  More detail couldn't hurt, but the 70d is pretty much universally an improvement on the 7d.

Comment: The 7D is a great camera, but its getting long in the tooth. Most of the rumour sites say that the 7D mark 2 is do out Real Soon Now, but they have been saying that for 2+ years.

If you need a camera in a month or so, I say get the 70D.

Comment: Keep waiting for the 7D Mark two. It will be steps above the 70D.

Comment: Do you have insider information on the impending release of the 7D MkII? How do you know this is a fact, or are you speculating?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would wait for the 70d if you can.  It's cheaper and pretty much an all around better camera.  Stat for stat, the only advantages the 7D has is that it shoots 1 frame per second faster, which is insignificant compared to the numerous improvements in the 70d, and the 100% coverage viewfinder compared to the 98% coverage viewfinder in the 70d.  While 100% coverage is nice to have, it isn't a super huge deal to miss the 2%, particularly when looking at 11% more image data (5% bigger in each direction), the wifi capability, the live view phase detect auto focus, the DIGIC 5 vs DIGIC 4 processor, the newer sensor, etc, etc.

Comment: Does the 70D have GPS? I haven't seen anything that suggests that the GPS functionality from the 6D has carried over. Also, IMHO, the only reason to prefer the 7D is the build quality/weather sealing compared to the 70D.

Comment: No it does not have GPS built in, it has Wi-Fi built in though.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi - good catch, I missed that.  Updated.  Btw, if you see an error like that, feel free to simply edit and then post a comment as to why.

Comment: I should add, even if you _do_ go for the 7D, it's probably worth waiting till September anyway to see if the price drops. The 70D is so close to the 7D feature-wise that I'd expect the 7D to end up heavily discounted (like the current EOS-M bodies).